# Insert a blank row into a csv using Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm looking to insert a blank row to the top of a csv. I can't figure out how to do this?

```
#df_marks = df_marks.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

#header_list = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
#ordersUnleashed = pd.read_csv("ClientOrders.csv", names=header_list)

#insert empty row up top
#ordersUnleashed.iloc[0] = [''] * 30
#ordersUnleashed.loc['0'] = ['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''

#set headers or move rows down one and add columns
ordersUnleashed.columns = ["*Order Number", "*Customer Code", "Tax Code", "Tax Rate", "Exchange Rate", "Customer Reference", "Comments", "Order Date (DD/MM/YYYY)", "Quote Expiry Date (DD/MM/YYYY)", "Required Date (DD/MM/YYYY)", "Warehouse Code", "Delivery Contact", "Delivery Name", "Delivery Street Address", "Delivery Street Address 2", "Delivery Suburb", "Delivery City", "Delivery Region", "Delivery Post Code", "Delivery Country", "Delivery Instruction", "Discount (%)", "Sales Order Group", "Sales Person Email", "*Line Number"," *Product Code", "*Order Quantity", "Line Discount (%)", "Unit Price", "Line Comments"]
df.head()
```

Further to this, what I was trying to achieve is now answered over here.
[Pandas CSV and Headers - CSV imports first row as actual header. If add a header, it overwrites rather than inserts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73478565/pandas-csv-and-headers-csv-imports-first-row-as-actual-header-if-add-a-header)

Comment: It's not clear what your code block is showing and how it relates to your question.

Comment: Answer is posted over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73478565/pandas-csv-and-headers-csv-imports-first-row-as-actual-header-if-add-a-header

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the functionality exists in pandas. `to_csv()` does accept any file object though, so you can simply write a line to the file and then have pandas append to the bottom of this open file.

```py
with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
  f.write('\n')
  df.to_csv(path_or_buf=f, index=False)
```

Comment: Thankyou - I think you're right, but I'm struggling to find how to add the blank row at the beginning of the CSV? Where the header would usually go.

Comment: ```f.write('\n')``` will do this

Comment: Thankyou, I just tried this and it worked, but it adds on the last row rather than inserting on the 1st row?

Comment: you will need to add your code to your original question. The ```f.write()``` needs to go before writing the csv. If it's an existing file you can't just insert a new line at the start of the file, you have to write the entire file again, kind of like a printer/photocopier.