# Pandas CSV and Headers - CSV imports first row as actual header. If add a header, it overwrites rather than inserts?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm using https://www.stackvidhya.com/how-to-add-header-to-pandas-dataframe/ for reference.

I have a CSV which for some reason, imports the first 'row' as the headers. So if I go to 'add' headers, ie the real headers, it just overwrites the first row.

Is there a way around this?

Code & Examples:

```
import pandas as pd
nocolumns = pd.read_csv("nocolumns.csv")
```

[nocolumns csv example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkZLn.png)

```
#add columns
nocolumns.columns = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"]
```

[columns added, but overwriting 1st row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fISyw.png)

how do I add the headers properly without over-writing the first row?

Comment: pass a `header` parameter to the `read_csv` method: `nocolumns = pd.read_csv("nocolumns.csv", header=None)`, then the behavior works as described in the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can supply the header and names arguments as so:

```
nocolumns = pd.read_csv("nocolumns.csv", header=None, names=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"])
```

Answer (score 0):

First call `header=None`, and then assign column names:

```
nocolumns = pd.read_csv("nocolumns.csv", header=None)
nocolumns.columns = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"]
```